# Magento Admin Area Customization

Tags: php, magento

I'm using Magento 1.9.1 and I need to customize System -> Import/Export -> Export page, but I have no idea how to do that.

Firstly, I tried to find some rules for admin area routing in `/Core/Mage/Adminhtml` directory. Then I tried to find something in ImportExport dir, but haven't find something helpful. Of course I have read all these guides about magento routing and modules system, but it didn't help me. And yet another thing I confused with - i tried to rename `/et`c directory in `/Core/Mage/Adminhtml` and `/Core/Mage/ImportExport`, but admin area and Import/Export module continued to work fine. Why? For all I know `/etc` dir is important part of module's settings... Please help me guys

Answer (score 0):

Some part is coming from importexport module and some from adminhtml.
You can check this by going to directory app/etc/modules/Mage_ImportExport.xml
set active to false.After that you will see lesser things related to import export on admin panel.